# Change URL in address bar

Tags: url-rewriting, url-mapping

I want to change my urls in my website. I read some articles and now, i know how to rewrite urls like this :

Users type in address bar => www.example.com/Q1
and loaded page is => www.example.com/dir1/cat.aspx?id=Q1

But i want this :

Users type in address bar => www.example.com/dir1/cat.aspx?id=Q1
and browsers show in address bar => www.example.com/othername/Q1

is there any way for this?

---

this is part of my webconfig about rewrite :

```html
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite page to aspx" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite item ID" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^items/([0-9]+)$" ignoreCase="false"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="items.aspx?id={R:1}"/>
      </rule>
      <rule name="Redirect to clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
      </rule>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html
You can achive this using a redirect directive or similar in your .htaccess file.

Comment: My host is windows. Does it work?

Comment: Which webserver are you using? If you're running IIS then I think you should enable `ISAPIRewrite`

Comment: Whoops, I think my rule is working the other way around, but you should get the idea =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find my real answer. but i found a simple way to rewrite my urls without any settings and modules that solved my problem partly :

you can rewrite in *global.asax* :

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strCurrentPath;
        String strCustomPath;
        strCurrentPath = Request.Path;
        if ( strCurrentPath.EndsWith("/home/"))
        {
            strCustomPath = strCurrentPath.Replace("/home/", "/presentation/default.aspx");
            Context.RewritePath(strCustomPath);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (strCurrentPath.Contains("/dir1/"))
            {
                strCustomPath = strCurrentPath.Replace("/dir1/", "/othername/cat.aspx?cid=");
                Context.RewritePath(strCustomPath);
                return;
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache this could be done by adding the following into an `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# check if the query string contains an `id` equal to `Q1`
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=Q1
# rewrite `dir1/cat.aspx` to `othername/Q1`
RewriteRule dir1/cat.aspx http://www.example.com/othername/Q1? [R=301,L]
```

In the case of a `web.config` file the above should look something like:

```
<rule name="rule 1k" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="dir1/cat.aspx"  />
  <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^id=Q1" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="http://www.example.com/othername/Q1"  />
</rule>
```

**References**

[Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

[Translate .htaccess Content to IIS web.config](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig)

Comment: rewrite is not my problem. i want to change url in my address bar after type it automatically. for example : i write : www.example.com/presentation/default.aspx then after load page in address bar url www.example.com

Comment: @mahdi - Yes and the `R` flag will do this for you.

Comment: @mahdi - Can you be more specific? Can you use an `.htaccess` file? The above should redirect `http://www.example.com/dir1/cat.aspx?id=Q1` to `http://www.example.com/othername/Q1` and it works just fine when I test it locally? And it also updates the url in the adressbar.

Comment: i can not use .htaccess but i write commands in .webconfig like  described in "Translate .htaccess Content to IIS web.config". when i write  http://www.example.com/home/ browser shows www.example.com/presentation/default.aspx but when i write www.example.com/presentation/default.aspx browser shows it without change.

Comment: @mahdi - okay, but what isn't working, like I said I've tried the above locally and it redirects as expected and change the value in the adressbar?

Comment: @mahdi - Are you sure you have installed the rewrite module for your server? http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module
I also think you will need to restart your server after modifying the contents of your web.config

Comment: i think it installed because when i write www.example.com/home browser shows www.example.com/presentation/default.aspx and url is www.example.com/home

Comment: @mahdi - Can you show the contents of your `web.config`, I also added a configuration for a `web.config` file into my answer.

Comment: i use parallels control panel for my site. how to install  rewrite module on server for publish my site?is it easy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS - URL Rewrite.

This is an additional module that you will need to install.
Once you have installed this, you can find it on the dashboard.
From here, add a rule to change the incoming URL to the desired URL.

Here is a fantastic guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkEFPzixiVE